# Dapper.Plus BulkInsert exception Invalid Object when Object exist

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dapper-plus

Trying to insert records using Dapper.Plus Bulk Insert operation for SQL database following their [guide](https://zzzcode.ai/answer-question?p1=Dapper%20ORM&p2=Give%20me%20an%20example%20of%20bulk%20insert%20using%20dapper%20plus%0D%0A%0D%0A).

I can create my List and add my results to it so it is populated. But then I am catching an   Inner Exception: Invalid object name 'TimingDataApp'.

But that's the List object that was just created and populated. Setting up a few breakpoints I can validate it exists and is populated.

Am I missing something?

Relevant code showing the creation, population and try/catch.

```
            //Create the List and add results
            List<TimingDataApp> timingDataApp = new List<TimingDataApp>();
            foreach (var result in exercises)
            {
                 timingDataApp.Add(new TimingDataApp() { AppId = result, SessionId = sessionKeyId, Urgency = 0, AppSatusId = 6 });
            }

            //Bulk Insert the records using Dapper.Plus
            //List<TimingDataApp> timingDataApp now contains approx
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(bulkDBConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.BulkInsert(timingDataApp);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) //This catches error: Inner Exception: Invalid object name 'TimingDataApp'.
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some coffee and more digging, it looks like the AI guide misses the step to add your class and table name with the DapperPlusManager. It should have been more obvious since I should have asked where/how is it going to know what table to insert into.

Hopefully my goof helps someone else out.

```
    DapperPlusManager.Entity<Customer>().Table("Customers");
```